# Why is the seed method not being called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, seeding

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and would like some help to execute the seed method to populate the database with some entities.

Here is my `DbContext` code:

```
public class CanFindLocationDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public class SystemInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CanFindLocationDatabaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(CanFindLocationDatabaseContext context)
        {

        }
    }   
}
```

In my `Application_Start` method I have the following code:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<CanFindLocationDatabaseContext>(new CanFindLocation.Context.CanFindLocationDatabaseContext.SystemInitializer());
```

When I access any of the `DbSet` objects in the `CanFindLocationDatabaseContext` class, the seed method is not being executed. There is no database before I test the seed code.

The database is being created and the tables are being created, yet the seed method is not called and there is not data in any of the tables.

I also have the following code for identity 2.1 in the same project:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("CanFindLocationDatabaseContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

The seed method is called for this DbContext class, but not for the `CanFindLocationDatabaseContext`.

Why is this, and how can I write my code so that the seed method is executed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you know for sure that the database doesn't exist?

Comment: The database does not exist.

Comment: Make sure you reset IIS or stop your ASP Developpement server before launching debug Or visual won't stop and restart you application and prevent Application_Start to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database is lazy loaded and will only be created when accessed, so if you need it for seeding you need to either access the context within the Seed() or you can add:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<CanFindLocationDatabaseContext>(new CanFindLocation.Context.CanFindLocationDatabaseContext.SystemInitializer());
var db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext()
db.Database.Initialize(true);   // force database creation
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

All along I thought the seed method was not being called when it was my fault. I had initially set the `"launchBrowser"` property in my `launchSettings.json` to `false` so I just changed it to `true` and it was resolved...database was seeded!

[image: launchSettings.json screenshot]